# displaying many to many relationship results and group them by the same id

Tags: mysql, vue.js

```js
methods : {

    fetch(){
    
          axios.get('api/parcels/to-pack')
          .then(response => this.parcels = response.data)
          .catch(error => console.log(error.response.data));

        } , 
        
    

}
```

```html
  <div class="todo animated fadeinright delay-1" id="test1">
   <p class="todo-element" v-for="(parcel,index) in parcels" :key="parcel.id">
    <delivery-parcel :parcel="parcel"></delivery-parcel>
        
       
        
        
   </p>
  </div>
    
    
    
    DeliveryParcel Component : 
    

          <input :id="'todo'+id" type="checkbox" :checked="isPacked">

      <label :for="'todo'+id">Parcel : {{ id }}</label> 

      <span>Owner : {{ name }}</span>

      <span>Medicine ID : {{ medicine_id }} - {{ qty }} pcs </span>
```

- In my results : I have results that have

  [

  ```
     {

     parcel_id : 2

     package_id : 4

     quantity : 3,

     owner  : {

     id : 4030523 , 

     name : 'john doe' ,

     }

     }, { parcel_id : 2

     package_id : 5

     quantity : 6,

     owner  : {

     id : 4030523 ,  name : 'john doe' ,

     other fields...
   } 

     },

     },
     ]
  ```

  What I want is to just display the results by their common key which is parcel_id. My current view displays like these :

[image]

But what I want is to display them like their grouped by their common key which is parcel_id

so Something like

[] Parcel:1

Medicine_id : 3 - 3pcs

Medicine_id : 2 - 3pcs

Medicine_id : 1 - 5pcs

[ ] Parcel : 11

Medicine_id : 3 - 3pcs

Medicine_id : 2 - 3pcs

Medicine_id : 1 - 5pcs

Comment: Your question is impossible to understand. Paste the code that you are using, show what you are getting and what you thought you should get.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new computed property to transform your data and use it instead, maybe something like this:

```
data() { 
    jsonData: [ /* ... */ ]
},
created() { /* ... */ },
computed: {
    transformedData() {
        return this.jsonData.reduce((acc, curr) => {
            const parcelId = curr.parcel_id; 
            if (Array.isArray(acc.parcelId)) {
                acc[parcelId].push(curr);
            } else {
                acc[parcelId] = [curr];
            }
            return acc;
        }, {});        
    }
}
```